column not found but column exists in laravel query
Below is my query in laravel project.In this query purchase_return_products.purchase amount actually exists but this show error

'[2024-07-14 16:28:02] local.ERROR: Errors: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column
not found: 1054 Unknown column
'purchase_return_products.purchase_amount' in 'field list'
(Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select
IFNULL(SUM(purchase_products.quantity), 0) as purchase_quantity,
IFNULL(SUM(purchase_products.purchase_amount), 0) as purchase_amount,
purchase_products.product_id, IFNULL(SUM(sale_products.quantity),
0) as sale_quantity, IFNULL(SUM(sale_products.sale_purchase_amount),
0) as sale_purchase_amount,
IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.quantity), 0) as
purchase_return_quantity,
IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_amount), 0) as
purchase_return_amount from products left join (SELECT product_id,
SUM(purchase_products.quantity) as quantity,
SUM(purchase_products.purchase_amount) as purchase_amount FROM
purchase_products GROUP BY product_id) as purchase_products on
purchase_products.product_id = products.identity left join
(SELECT product_id, SUM(sale_products.quantity) as quantity,
SUM(sale_products.sale_purchase_amount) as sale_purchase_amount FROM
sale_products GROUP BY product_id) as sale_products on
sale_products.product_id = products.identity left join (SELECT
product_id, SUM(purchase_return_products.quantity) as quantity,
SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_amount) as
purchase_return_amount FROM purchase_return_products GROUP BY
product_id) as purchase_return_products on
purchase_return_products.product_id = products.identity where
products.store_id = 2024061225851482 group by
purchase_products.product_id having (purchase_quantity -
(purchase_return_quantity + sale_quantity)) > 0) as
aggregate_table)'

Please help me solving this problem.
$data = $this->helper_object->getModel('Product')::select(
                    DB::raw('IFNULL(SUM(purchase_products.quantity), 0) as purchase_quantity'),
                    DB::raw('IFNULL(SUM(purchase_products.purchase_amount), 0) as purchase_amount'),
                   'purchase_products.product_id',
                    DB::raw('IFNULL(SUM(sale_products.quantity), 0) as sale_quantity'),
                    DB::raw('IFNULL(SUM(sale_products.sale_purchase_amount), 0) as sale_purchase_amount'),
                    DB::raw('IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.quantity), 0) as purchase_return_quantity'),
                    DB::raw('IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_amount), 0) as purchase_return_amount')
                )
                ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT product_id, SUM(purchase_products.quantity) as quantity, SUM(purchase_products.purchase_amount) as purchase_amount FROM purchase_products GROUP BY product_id) as purchase_products'), function($join) {
                    $join->on('purchase_products.product_id', '=', 'products.identity');
                    })
                ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT product_id, SUM(sale_products.quantity) as quantity, SUM(sale_products.sale_purchase_amount) as sale_purchase_amount FROM sale_products GROUP BY product_id) as sale_products'), function($join) {
                    $join->on('sale_products.product_id', '=', 'products.identity');
                    })
                ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT product_id, SUM(purchase_return_products.quantity) as quantity, SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_amount) as purchase_return_amount FROM purchase_return_products GROUP BY product_id) as purchase_return_products'), function($join) {
                    $join->on('purchase_return_products.product_id', '=', 'products.identity');
                    })
                ->where('products.store_id', $store_id)
                ->when($query, function ($queryBuilder) use ($query) {
                      $queryBuilder->where(function ($innerQueryBuilder) use ($query) {
                         $innerQueryBuilder->where('products.name', 'like', "%$query%")
                                           ->orWhere('products.sku_code_number', 'like', "%$query%");
                                           });
                                         })
                ->when($brand, function ($queryBuilder) use ($brand) {
                      $queryBuilder->where(function ($innerQueryBuilder) use ($brand) {
                         $innerQueryBuilder->where('products.brand', $brand);
                                           });
                                         })
                ->when($category, function ($queryBuilder) use ($category) {
                      $queryBuilder->where(function ($innerQueryBuilder) use ($category) {
                         $innerQueryBuilder->where('products.category', $category);
                                           });
                                         })
                ->groupBy('purchase_products.product_id')
                ->havingRaw('(purchase_quantity - (purchase_return_quantity + sale_quantity)) > 0')
                ->orderBy('products.sku_code_number', 'asc')
                ->paginate(30);

This is my purchase_return_products table schema :-
   Schema::create('purchase_return_products', function (Blueprint 
                $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('identity',16)->unique()->index();
                $table->string('purchase_identity',16)->index();
                $table->string('unique_identity',16)->index();
                $table->string('invoice_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('warehouse_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('store_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('parent_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('party_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('product_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('variant_id',16)->index();
                $table->string('serial',120)->nullable()->index();
                $table->decimal('quantity', 25, 3)->index();
                $table->decimal('purchase_price', 25, 3)->index();
                $table->decimal('purchase_amount', 25, 3)->index();
                $table->decimal('unit_offer', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
                $table->decimal('total_offer', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->date('date')->index();
                $table->string('status',10)->default('Pending')->index();
                $table->string('added_by',16)->index();
                $table->string('updated_by',16)->nullable();

This is my sale_products table schema :-
   Schema::create('sale_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('identity',16)->unique()->index();
            $table->string('warehouse_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('store_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('parent_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('party_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('purchase_identity',16)->index();
            $table->string('product_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('variant_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('invoice_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('serial',120)->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('sale_type',10)->default('Sale')->index();
            $table->decimal('quantity', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('purchase_price', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('sale_purchase_amount', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('sale_price', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('sale_amount', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('discount_percent', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->decimal('total_discount', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('offer_id',16)->nullable()->index();
            $table->decimal('unit_offer', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->decimal('total_offer', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->decimal('profit', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->date('warranty_date')->nullable()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->date('date')->index();
            $table->string('status',10)->default('Pending')->index();
            $table->string('added_by',16)->index();
            $table->string('updated_by',16)->nullable();

This is my purchase_products table schema :-
   Schema::create('purchase_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('identity',16)->unique()->index();
            $table->string('warehouse_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('store_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('parent_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('party_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('product_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('variant_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('invoice_id',16)->index();
            $table->string('sale_status',9)->default('Running')->index();
            $table->string('serial',120)->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('purchase_type',10)->index();
            $table->decimal('quantity', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('purchase_price', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('purchase_amount', 25, 3)->index();
            $table->decimal('unit_offer', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->decimal('total_offer', 25, 3)->nullable()->index();
            $table->date('expire_date')->nullable()->index();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->date('date')->index();
            $table->string('status',10)->default('Pending')->index();
            $table->string('added_by',16)->index();
            $table->string('updated_by',16)->nullable();


What exactly is your question, what do you want us to do? Not seeing your database structure makes this hard if not impossible to resolve.

I updated my question with adding database table schema.please help me @brombeer

In the subquery for `purchase_return_products' you already renamed/aliased purchase_amount as purchase_return_amount  :
left join (
        SELECT 
          product_id, 
          SUM(purchase_return_products.quantity) as quantity, 
          SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_amount) as purchase_return_amount 
        FROM 
          purchase_return_products 
        GROUP BY 
          product_id
      ) as purchase_return_products 

But then on the main query you still refer to it as purchase_amount, as in:
   select 
      IFNULL(SUM(purchase_products.quantity), 0) as purchase_quantity, 
      IFNULL(SUM(purchase_products.purchase_amount), 0) as purchase_amount, 
      purchase_products.product_id,
      IFNULL(SUM(sale_products.quantity), 0) as sale_quantity, 
      IFNULL(SUM(sale_products.sale_purchase_amount), 0) as sale_purchase_amount, 
      IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.quantity), 0) as purchase_return_quantity, 
      IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_amount), 0) as purchase_return_amount 
    from 
    
      products ...

Change that to IFNULL(SUM(purchase_return_products.purchase_return_amount ), 0) as purchase_return_amount 
